# rails save how many times a page has been viewed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i'm wanting to save a number of how many times an event has been viewed. Basically this is to assist me order the popularity of the events.

So i would do it on when the db row is selected but my searchkick is selecting the rows to show back.

So i don't think i have any other choice but to put it in the show method?

Heres whats in my show method (thats important)

```
def show
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

what would be the best way to have it count when the view is shown? Ideally it would be amazing if i could also have it so it was unique to ip address (so someone can't spam the url)

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the callback. Add the field named 'views' to your Events model.
Add this filter:

```
after_action :log_impression, only: [:show]
....
def log_impression
  @event.views += 1 
  @event.save
end
```

More concise variant:

```
....
def log_impression
  @event.increment!(:views)
end
```

Now you can sort events by the number of impressions.

IP isn't good solution against spam (dynamic IPs, shared wi-fi and so on). Consider using the combination of IP with something else (e.g., session, user agent).

There is a gem [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist). It will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You would need another Model with a table that has a column to save the ip-address. Then implement the logic for unique ip-addresses per event.id.
And create an entry for that model directly after loading the event by passing the ip-address.
A counter cache column on the Event model would be a good idea for it.

Create a model named `EventView`with a string column `ip_address` and integer `event_id` to reference the event. `EventView` gets `belongs_to :event`and
in your controller`s show action you do this:

```
EventView.where(event: @event, ip_address: request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']).first_or_create
```

This will make sure each ip-address whill be logged per event.id

`Event` model then gets a `has_many :event_views`
And via `@event.event_views.count` you get the number of unique views

Comment: I'm still kinda new to rails, How would i go about doing this o.o?

Comment: e.g. a new Model named EventView, add a string colum named ip_address.